# java regexp match morse code

Tags: java, regex, string, matching

I'm trying to test if the Morse code is legal.

```
public static boolean isMorseCode( String code ){
return code.trim().matches("[+.|+\s|+-]");      
}
```

The Morse code line can begin with a `.` (known as Dit) and a `-` (known as Dah). It can have spaces in the line.
1 space between two specific codes like `.- -.` in this case the sum of codes which are only separated by one white space is a word. But it can also have 3 white spaces and then a new word begins. I'm using trim to exclude the fact that there could be a white space at the beginning and end of the line.

Here an example to make it more clear.

We use "Hello World" for explanation. The white spaces are wiped out by posting them so take a look at http://www.rubular.com/r/r2iwqgUHCB there is also the regexp I used. In java it doesn't work.If someone could explain why it doesn't work or even show me how it does work I would be very thankful.

Comment: Im confused, what part doesnt work? I see what your input is, but Im not 100% sure what you want your output to be.

Comment: You are using a character class. Are you aware that in character classes, you can only match one character?

Comment: I try to explain. i want that the line can begin with a "." or an "-" it can have many dots or dashes but it must have one of both at least.
That means "." or "-" should be legal but it can have severel mixed codes and it can have whitespaces either 1 or 3 One will seperate the "Letters" or codes and 3 seperate the word but it should not be legal a different cuantity then 3 or 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can describe the morse code with this:

```
[.-]{1,5}(?> [.-]{1,5})*(?>   [.-]{1,5}(?> [.-]{1,5})*)*
```

each elements of the Morse alphabet have between 1 or 5 Dit or Dah.

each letters are separated by one space

each words are separated by three spaces

Answer (score 1):

It may be because `[+.|+\s|+-]` is a character class, so it may just be matching a single character.  Maybe what you want is `[.\s\-]+`.

Comment: i tried to use
    [.\s-]+ 
but eclipse is telling me that \s is an ivalid escape sequence.

Comment: @user2502106 use "[\\.\\s-]+"

Comment: @Smertokogt: No need to escape the dot in a character class. `[.\\s-]` is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

Out of curiosity why not just validate the string contains the known sequences?

This regex will match only match if the string contains valid Morse code letters, punctuation, or numbers. Any white space at the beginning or end of the string is just ignored automatically. And the expression requires either 1 or 3 spaces between characters.

`^\s*(?:\s*(?:\.-|-\.\.\.|-\.-\.|-\.\.|\.|\.\.-\.|--\.|\.\.\.\.|\.\.|\.---|-\.-|\.-\.\.|--|-\.|---|\.--\.|--\.-|\.-\.|\.\.\.|-|\.\.-|\.\.\.-|\.--|-\.\.-|-\.--|--\.\.|-----|\.----|\.\.---|\.\.\.--|\.\.\.\.-|\.\.\.\.\.|-\.\.\.\.|--\.\.\.|---\.\.|----\.|\.-\.-\.-|--\.\.--|\.\.--\.\.|\.----\.|-\.-\.--|-\.\.-\.|-\.--\.|-\.--\.-|\.-\.\.\.|---\.\.\.|-\.-\.-\.|-\.\.\.-|\.-\.-\.|-\.\.\.\.-|\.\.--\.-|\.-\.\.-\.|\.\.\.-\.\.-|\.--\.-\.)(?=\s|\s{3}|\s*$))+\s*$`

## Java code example

**Code**

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
class Module1{
  public static void main(String[] asd){
  String sourcestring = "         .... . .-.. .-.. ---   .-- --- .-. .-.. -..      ";
  Pattern re = Pattern.compile("^\\s*((?:\\s*?(?:\\.-|-\\.\\.\\.|-\\.-\\.|-\\.\\.|\\.|\\.\\.-\\.|--\\.|\\.\\.\\.\\.|\\.\\.|\\.---|-\\.-|\\.-\\.\\.|--|-\\.|---|\\.--\\.|--\\.-|\\.-\\.|\\.\\.\\.|-|\\.\\.-|\\.\\.\\.-|\\.--|-\\.\\.-|-\\.--|--\\.\\.|-----|\\.----|\\.\\.---|\\.\\.\\.--|\\.\\.\\.\\.-|\\.\\.\\.\\.\\.|-\\.\\.\\.\\.|--\\.\\.\\.|---\\.\\.|----\\.|\\.-\\.-\\.-|--\\.\\.--|\\.\\.--\\.\\.|\\.----\\.|-\\.-\\.--|-\\.\\.-\\.|-\\.--\\.|-\\.--\\.-|\\.-\\.\\.\\.|---\\.\\.\\.|-\\.-\\.-\\.|-\\.\\.\\.-|\\.-\\.-\\.|-\\.\\.\\.\\.-|\\.\\.--\\.-|\\.-\\.\\.-\\.|\\.\\.\\.-\\.\\.-|\\.--\\.-\\.)(?=\\s|\\s{3}|\\s*$))+)\\s*$",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
  Matcher m = re.matcher(sourcestring);
    if(m.find()){
      for( int groupIdx = 0; groupIdx < m.groupCount()+1; groupIdx++ ){
        System.out.println( "[" + groupIdx + "] = " + m.group(groupIdx));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Output**

Capture group 0 gets the entire matching input string. Group 1 gets the trimmed sentence.

```
[0] =>          .... . .-.. .-.. ---   .-- --- .-. .-.. -..      
[1] => .... . .-.. .-.. ---   .-- --- .-. .-.. -..
```

The regex will return nothing (aka false) if the string is not valid.

Comment: If I understood correctly this pattern checks for every single morse code. That means that it can be(or maybe you did it already) put in a certain sequence sorted by which letters are most used. Am I right ? @Denomales

Comment: I can't say every, but it is all the letter, numbers, and many symbols. The list is in alphabetical order. But as far as the regular expression engine is concerned the order is arbitrary. Depending on the size of string you're searching in you may gain some benefit from reorganizing the expression.