# Flex regex for text including spaces eg "-.-. --.- -.-. --.-"

Tags: regex, flexbox

I'm use to PCRE, but I'm using Flex which has some limited functionality with the **regex** and references. I can't seem to find a way to grab all the morse code as a single token. I thought it would be similar to a quoted string. Last character would be [-.], and start would be [-.]. But also the whole of the **morse code** could be just one byte like ".". I could mandate it start with **"morse code"** as the start. But I couldn't get that to work.

**my Example**: This is morse code -.-. --.- for CQ.

I'd like to pull the complete **morse code** word as one token "-.-. --.-" or "morse code -.-. --.-" which can consist of a dash '-', a dot '.' and a space. Which I can pass into a decoder. I could easily pull out fixed text at the beginning, but I have no guarantee what is at the end of the line.

**I've seen this regex**

```
[.-]{1,5}(?:[ \t]+[.-]{1,5})*(?:[ \t]+[.-]{1,5}(?:[ \t]+[.-]{1,5})*)*
```

but it uses the (?: notation that is not supported by Flex.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try this page? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197887/java-regexp-match-morse-code or change the `(?:` to `(`

Comment: You wrote "Last character would be [-.]" - did you mean to write "[.-]"?